# xslt to move a node under second node into first node and remove second node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<release>
    <changerequest>101</changerequest>
    <morechangerequest />
    <year>1998</year>
</release>
<release>
    <year>1998</year>
    <remarks>
        <remarkname>name</remarkname>
        <remarktitle>remarktitle</remarktitle>
    </remarks>
    <remarks>
        <remarkname>name2</remarkname>
        <remarktitle>remarktitle2</remarktitle>
    </remarks>
    <moreremarks />
</release>
    <othertags />
</root>
```

I would like to have output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<release>
    <changerequest>101</changerequest>
    <morechangerequest/>
    <year>1998</year>
    <remarks>
        <remarkname>name</remarkname>
        <remarktitle>remarktitle</remarktitle>
    </remarks>
    <remarks>
        <remarkname>name2</remarkname>
        <remarktitle>remarktitle2</remarktitle>
    </remarks>
    <moreremarks/>
</release>
    <othertags />
</root>
```

That is, move all the remarks tags under the second release tag to first release tag, then delete the second release tag.

The XSLT I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|//release[1]/*"/>
                    <remarks>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|//release[2]/remarks/*"/>
                    </remarks>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//release[2]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are two problems with it:

1. It removed everything else except release tag the  in the xml.
2. Only one remarks tag is preserved.

Any lights? Thanks,

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Updated with my xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> move all the remarks tags under the second release tag to first
>   release tag, then delete the second release tag.

This could be done as follows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <release>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="release[1]/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="release[2]/remarks"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::release)]"/>
        </release>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```